# How do I create this graphic design in Affinity Designer?

Tags: affinity-designer

[image]

How to get some of these brush strokes at front/back of the square?

Comment: Does it have some sort of brush tool? That would be the first place I would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinity Design hasn't artistic paint brushes by default. Fortunately defining them is not difficult. Have a greyshade PNG image file of a brush stroke and define it to be a new Texturized Image Brush (it's in the small menu of the brushes panel at top right)

I made one brush stroke in a photo editor. It's drawn with mouse. Several simpler strokes are combined to get some richness. The blurriness was reduced by posterizing it to few greyshades.

The fake stroke isn't especially plausible, but better than existing ready to use brushes:

[image]

For high quality results use an image of a real brush stroke or do it in a painting program.

In Affinity designer the PNG was defined to be my new Texturized Image Brush and several slightly differently colored lines were drawn with the vector brush.

One way to cover parts of the rectangle is to drag some lines above the rectangle in Layers panel.

In your example some parts of the rectangle are cut off or hidden with a mask. This way the painted area can well be a single object.

Here the rectangle is above the lines, it has a manually drawn clipping mask:

[image]